# Why coming dates from csv display as numbers in php side?

Tags: php, date, csv

Well, I don't know why it's happening but my following date field of excel displayed as numbers not even timestamp.

Screenshot of my excel csv file date field.
[image: csv file date field snap shot]

Now, when I read CSV date field will shows this date as following numbers in combobox using php and I don't know why it's displaying like that and what should I do to convert back to my csv file date.
Following date is displayed when I do data[$k] to do csv file reading:
41724 and 41731 and so on in combobox. What to do?

My code:

```
while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {

        if($row == 10) {

            break;
        }
        else { 
            if($mycount == 0) {
                $mycount = 1;
                $field_name = $data[$k];
                $tot_combo = $tot_combo + 1;
            } else {
                **$user_data[]** = $data[$k]; //where date coming here

            }
            $row = $row+1;
        }
    }
```

So after did some more research I found in csv excel file my date column is assigned as date and when reading file in php it convert that date column to text which will return me 41708 not 10/03/2014 any idea how to achieve this Thanks

Comment: You should add some relevant code if you want answers.

Comment: Check the formatting in Excel (right click a cell and select "Format Cell") - make sure it's using the appropriate date format for what you're trying to export.

Comment: A snippet of the csv file would be useful as well.. Remember there are no dates in a csv file (its text!), there are strings or numbers that represent a date in some format.

Comment: Thanks try out by format cell and select "Date" in excel but still getting 41724 like that:(

Comment: I think it;s coming out as text when I am extracting data from csv file because if I format cell to csv date column to text then it gives me only 5 number which I am getting in my output in php. So what I do in excel or php side to if I receive date from csv then display as it is as date.

Comment: @user2268488: like already said, can you show us the raw csv data???

Comment: what you mean by this my friend as I think if you talking about code than I am pasting above and my csv excel file date field screenshot I already displayed as an image I think

Comment: No, you posted an __MS Excel__ screenshot, show the raw data, as you'd see it if you opened the file in a text editor

Answer (score 2):

Because that number is an MS Excel serialized timestamp, it's how MS Excel stores date values and then uses a number format mask to render them as a human readable date.

A quick and dirty conversion to a PHP DateTime object:

```
function ExcelToPHPObject($excelDateTime = 0) {
    $calendarBaseLine = '1899-12-30';
    if ($excelDateTime < 60) {
        // 29th February will be treated as 28th February
        ++$excelDateTime;
    }

    return (new \DateTime($calendarBaseLine, new \DateTimeZone('UTC')))
        ->modify('+' . floor($excelDateTime) . ' days')
        ->modify('+' . floor(fmod($excelDateTime, 1) * 86400) . ' seconds');
}
```

This function will return a PHP DateTime object (assumes MS Excel Windows 1900 calendar), and you can then use the DateTime object's `format()` method to format the date/time however you want, so:

```
$excelDateTime = 41724;
echo ExcelToPHPObject($excelDateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Elaborate on the error? How do you expect @Mark to follow up?

Comment: The code that I posted works - [Demo](http://ideone.com/dLsyu6) - If you're getting an error, then clarify exactly what error you're getting from this code

Comment: awesome bro, you save me